# Test whether a number is within 100 of 1000 or 2000

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just a beginner in programming but this is bugging me and I can't find anything online about this. 
Please help me with this..

```
def function(num):
    if (abs(num-1000) > 100) or (abs(num-2000) > 100):
        return False
    else:
        return True


print(function(1009))
print(function(2001))
print(function(1098))
print(function(500))
print(function(600))
```

when I write this the answer is different

```
#Python program to test whether a number is within 100 of 1000 or 2000
def function(num):

    if (abs(num-1000) < 100) or (abs(num-2000) < 100):
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(function(1009))
print(function(2001))
print(function(1098))
print(function(500))
print(function(600))
```

Greater than comparison gives all output False.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: The output is different when I change the lesser than to greater than..

Comment: see my answer. cheers

Comment: You also need  to change `or` to `and` @ro.mann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, because you have an logical `or` between your statements, so if one of the two conditions is `true` your function will return `false`. Additional you use the function [abs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abs-in-python/) which converts negative numbers into positive numbers (or an absolute number).

So i. e. your line `print(function(500))` will do this (for the fourth line):

```
500 - 1000 = -500
abs(-500) = 500
if(500 > 100):
   return false
```

You see that your function will always use one argument as `true`, which means that your `or` condition is met. So your `if` is also `true` and your code will jump in the first block of your `if`.

When you change your comparison into the following

```
def function(num):
    if (abs(num-1000) < 100) or (abs(num-2000) < 100):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

you get (for the first line) the following code:

```
1009-1000=9
abs(9) = 9
if(100 < 9): <- This is false, so return True
```

Comment: You´re welcome :). Please mark the abswer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need the logical `and`.

```
def function1(num):
    if (abs(num-1000) > 100) and (abs(num-2000) > 100):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def function2(num):

    if (abs(num-1000) < 100) or (abs(num-2000) < 100):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(function1(1009))
print(function1(2001))
print(function1(1098))
print(function1(500))
print(function1(600))

True
True
True
False
False

print(function2(1009))
print(function2(2001))
print(function2(1098))
print(function2(500))
print(function2(600))

True
True
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You're combining the sub-clauses incorrectly: you want to know if `(abs(num-1000) < 100) or (abs(num-2000) < 100)`.

In the first version you want to write the sub-clauses the other way around (using greater than), so you need to negate it, and apply [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to push the negation to the leaves (or from the leaves to the root, same difference).

That's where you failed `not (a or b)` is `not a and not b`, but you wrote `not a or not b`. The two clauses should be combined with an `and` not an `or`.

Your two solutions are also inconsistent with respect to boundary condition (aka whether 900 is ok or not).